# Use specific theme for WooCommerce store

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress website that contains a blog and a WooCommerce store. I want the WooCommerce part to have a specific theme alone (they have their menu). I'm thinking of something like detecting the URL and automatically choosing the best theme.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where's your code?  See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/. It lets you use different themes for different pages. Then use the option do detect by URL and set the theme of your liking. Let me know if you need further help.